# Do American views on national racial issues fall among party lines when controlling for race?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, demographics

Polls show that Democrats support "racial justice" ideas like equal prison sentences and slavery reparations at substantially higher rates than Republicans. For example, while [reparations](https://thehill.com/homenews/news/504511-1-in-5-supports-reparations-in-new-poll) is opposed by the majority of Americans across polls, a third of Democrats and half of Black Americans support it in a poll. Half of black Americans forms only about 10 percent of Democratic voters, and this poll placed support at 1/3 among Democrats.

*What I am asking is how much when breaking down by political affiliation AND race, support for racial reforms is different among say non-white Democrats vs non-white Republicans.*

Notes: certain segments may be hard to measure, such as Black or Asian Republicans, because they are such small portions of the population (both of those two is about one to three percent of the voting population each). Also, this is not designed to forward one side or another's political agenda. This question might be complicated and have a long answer because there are *multiple* racial issues, and I think some will fall along racial lines more than others. The reason this question is relevant is that polling talks about how racial and partisan groups view issues, which can be problematic since the two intersect in a statistically relevant way. For example, non-whites are substantially more likely to be Democrats, which means when Democrats and people of color support a given racial reform idea and Republicans and white people oppose it, it is hard to tell whether it is racial, partisan, or both.

Comment: "equal prison sentences" - what does it mean?

Comment: @markvs it means that there is an observable racial disparity in sentencing. I.e. on average a white person receives a milder sentence for the same crime than what a black person receives.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_of_Derek_Chauvin#Opinion_polling) is one example, regarding the trial of Derek Chauvin, who was found guilty of second-degree unintentional murder, third-degree murder, and second-degree manslaughter for the murder of George Floyd.

[Here](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/chauvin-verdict-opinion-poll/) is the source that Wikipedia gets it from.

> Three in four Americans share the view that the jury reached the right
> verdict in the trial of Derek Chauvin. Among White Americans, 90% of
> Democrats polled believe the right verdict was reached while only 54%
> of Republicans find the guilty decision to be correct. 93% of Black
> Americans agree with the decision. Polling shows that of the 25% who
> believe that the jury did not reach the right decision, they also
> "strongly disagree" with the beliefs of the Black Lives Matter
> movement. They largely identify as conservative, they are composed of
> more men than women, and they are disproportionately White. President
> Biden had a 60% approval rating for his handling of matters
> surrounding Floyd's murder and Chauvin's trial, similar to his overall
> job rating of his first 100 days in office.

While this may vary on other racial issues, there is a clear party-line divide here by race.

Comment: I believe the majority of people that disagree with the verdict is because the magnitude of the "excess justice exerted by the juries" is nearing the "excess of the force exerted by Derek Chauvin. If a fair question (more than just "yes" or "no") was asked, the result would be quite different.

Comment: There are several components that need to be evaluated before reaching a reasonable conclusion. If the question was asked this way - do you 1) support the presence of police in this case; 2) support the use of force to subdue an unruly person that is physically powerful and mentally influenced by drug; 3) agree that Derek Chauvin has exerted an excessive force that directly or indirectly caused the tragic death of George Floyd; 4) agree that Derek Chauvin is guilty of manslaughter, and 5) agree that a jail sentence is justified? We'll see quite different answers from every ethnic group.

Comment: @r13 I don't think so; didn't they just ask for a breakdown on views on race issues by race and political affilation?

Comment: It is wrong to paint the "black communities" are unified against the police, while not in love with, the sane black person recognizes the necessity of the presence of police force to protect them the inner-city crimes and acts of violence that mostly happen in the black majority communities in a daily basis. Examples - Chicago, New York, LA... All Democratic cities.

Comment: @r13 This source is not saying that "black communities" are unified against the police. It is saying that 93% of black persons polled agree with the verdict against Chauvin.

Comment: While the aforementioned cities are all controlled by the Democrats with the majority of residents being racial minorities and identifying themself as Democrate, yet the crime rate and poverty rate are high, and racial segregation is severe, WHY???!!!

Comment: @r13 Crime rates and poverty rates are generally higher in cities than they are anywhere else. I fail to see what you mean by "racial segregation".

Comment: As I've stated, the reason for the drastic contrast in polling percentage was because of the biasedly constructed question, and the 93% has led people to believe the Black communities are unified and used as a weapon in calling the "defunding/dissolve" the police force in many locals.

Comment: @r13 That is irrelevant. The question asks for a breakdown of American racial views by race and party line. I provided an example. Said example was not about "defunding the police", nor was it about "black communities". It was a poll, whose question was whether or not Americans agreed with the verdict against Chauvin. It also collected data on the race and political party of those responding to this poll. I believed that that data was relevant.

Comment: You need to follow inner-city news more often to understand the phenomenons I addressed. Segregation - Black, White, Hispanic, other minorities each live along the racial lines. Where is the integration promoted by DEM?

Comment: @r13 I am of the impression that you are not paying attention to what I am saying. I am not furthering this conversation.

Comment: I am commenting to address my concerns on citing the biased survey/polling, for which the result is biased too, misleading and divisive.

Comment: There is no "party line" in the US, because there are lots of independent people who are neither Democrats nor Republicans, neither conservative nor liberal, etc.

Comment: @markvs There may be lots of folks not *registered* with either party, but only 7% don't identify with one ([source](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2019/05/15/facts-about-us-political-independents/))

Comment: Now every election of a President costs about 1 B. I guess this is what it costs to convince the 7% which, by the way, is many millions of people.